# Can VS 2013 be installed on Server 2003 R2

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2003-r2

Can I install Visual Studio 2013 on Windows Server 2003 R2?

According to Visual Studio 2013 [System Requirements](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-ultimate-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_SystemRequirements) it is not supported. However I heard some users was able to install it. Was anybody able to install it on Server 2003 R2?

Comment: Even you can install it but you will not get the support from Microsoft if you do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS 2013 requires the .NET Framework 4.5.1, which in turn is not supported (and does not install) on 2003, you need Vista SP2 or newer or Server 2008 SP2 or newer. The same is true for VS 2012 which requires .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is 'no'.

I recently ran into a similar problem install VS 2012 on Windows Server 2008 (not R2). Running the **vs_premium.exe** gave me a pop-up saying "The specified program requires a newer version of Windows".

So, this is an older version of Visual Studio on a newer version of Windows Server and it doesn't install.