# Highest supported version of Visual Studio on Windows Server 2003 R2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I am starting a project that will be hosted in a environment relying on Windows Server 2003 R2 (SP2) and I will need to use features like WCF, services and so on... I would like to use the highest possible version of the Visual Studio and .Net Framework.

Which version is it possible to install in that environment?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886603/does-net-framework-4-5-work-on-windows-server-2003

Comment: Extended Support for Server 2003 ended on July 14, 2015, so I would question any project that expects to use that technology in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this Microsoft page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691 Visual Studio 2010 supports Server 2003 R2

And according to this Micosoft page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30682  Visual Studio 2012 does not.  Therefore I would have to say VS 2010.

Here's a more complete answer on VS 2013 that was posted a long time ago..
[Can VS 2013 be installed on Server 2003 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231319/can-vs-2013-be-installed-on-server-2003-r2)

Answer (score 1):

You can develop your app in another platform. You don't need to run visual studio on server side. 2003 R2 support framework 4.0 but not support 4.5. So you can develop WCF or another applications.